# Read file name then call the convenable function (with one or two arguments) using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, arguments, parameter-passing

I want to read file name(A/B/C/D) and call the convenable function for each file in **Files folder** and then process the *next file* (pass automatically to the next file and function).

I have multiple files stored in **Files folder:**

Here is the directory structure:

```
   App/  
   ├─ main.py
   └─ Files/  
      └─B.txt
      └─A.xlsx
      └─folderC
      |   └─filec1.txt
      |   └─filec2.txt
      └─D.xlsx    
      └─folderF
         └─fileF1.txt
         └─fileF2.txt
```

I have multiple functions stored in main.py:

```
def A_fct(fileA):
    pass
def B_fct(fileB):
    pass
def C_fct(fileC1,fileC2):
    pass
def D_fct(fileD):
    pass
def F_fct(files):
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f,sep='\t',engine="python") for f in 
        glob.glob(files + "/*.txt")],ignore_index=True)
```

NB: Somes functions have 2 arguments.

**Example:**

read file Name B.txt => call B_fct

read file Name A.xlsx => call A_fct

etc ...

I tried this solution:

```
path = ''

name_to_func = {
        "A.xlsx": A_fct,
        "B.txt": B_fct,
        ...
}

for files in os.listdir(path):
    name_to_func[file_name](files)
```

This solution is worked very well for me when functions **have only one argument** but sometimes I have exceptions and I have a fonction with ***2 arguments*** for Exp **C_fct(fileC1,fileC2)**

How can I fix this please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a path is a directory with `os.path.isdir` and change the call arguments.

```
base_path = 'Files/'
for name in os.listdir(base_path):
    path = os.path.join(base_path, name)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
        if name_to_func[path].__code__.co_argcount == len(files):
            name_to_func[path](*files)
        else:
            name_to_func[path](files)
    else:
        name_to_func[path](path)
```

In this case the list of files will be used as arguments to the function.

If you are not sure how many parameters would the function get you can rewrite the definition as well:

```
def C_fct(*files):
    files  # is the list of arguments
```

However, you can avoid `*` notation simply providing a list as an argument.

Comment: thanks for your help but it got this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filec1.txt'` how can i fix it plz

Comment: Most probably you need to join the file path with the base path, I updated the answer see the `[os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]` line

Comment: sorry for bothering you, what if i have files to concatenate in fct f how can i deal with it. this methods shows an error `TypeError:F_fct() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: If you have functions with different number of arguments for each directory then you can decide if you should run `name_to_func[path](files)` or `name_to_func[path](*files)` using the condition where you check the number of arguments for the function: `name_to_func[path].__code__.co_argcount == 2`

Comment: Updated. Now it checks if the number of arguments for the function matches the number of files. Otherwise provide one argument with the list of files.